# Ошибка в селект меню discord.py

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Вот я сделал пару импортов

```py
import discord
import json
import requests
import sqlite3
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle, component, ComponentsBot, Select, SelectOption
from discord_components import *
```

После этого я добавил эти строки:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  DiscordComponents(bot)
  print('BOT CONECTED')
```

Дале сделал команду хелпа и приделал к этой команде селект меню, кто не знает что это, лучше загуглите, так вот сам код:

```py
#Основная команда ХЕЛП
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx, comname: str = None):
  embed = discord.Embed(
        color = 0xff9900,
        title="Команды **LiteBot**",
        description="Для более детальной информации о команде, просто напишите >help (команда)\n**<:clipboard:920714709932593182> Основное**\n`>help` - все команды бота\n`>info` - информация о боте\n`>addbot` - добавить бота\n**<:shield:920714733278077010> Модерация**\n`>clear` - очистка сообщений\n`>mute` - заглушить пользователя\n`>unmute` - размутить пользователя\n`>kick` - выгнать пользователя\n`>ban` - забанить пользователя\n`>niсk` - сменить ник пользователю\n**<:wrench:920715659481075734> Утилиты**\n`>avatar` - просмотр аватара\n`>say` - писать от имени бота\n`>embsay` - писать вебхуком\n**<:smile:920714719873105951> Развлечения**\n`>fox` - рандомные фото лисичек\n`>dog` - рандомные фото собачек\n`>cat` - рандомные фото кошек\n**<:gear:920714911049478204> Настройки**\n`>automode` - вкл/выкл автомодерацию на мат",
        )
  embed.set_thumbnail(url = bot.user.avatar_url)
  embed.set_footer(text = 'halflite © 2021 Все права защищены')
  embinf = discord.Embed(title='`Информация о команде >info`', description='**Описание:**\nИнформация о данном боте', color=0xff9900)
  embinf.set_thumbnail(url = bot.user.avatar_url)
  if comname is None:
    await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
  else:
      if comname == 'info':
        await ctx.reply(embed=embinf)
      elif comname == 'addbot':
          embbod = discord.Embed(
          title='`Информация о команде >addbot`',
          description='**Описание:**\nКоманда для добавления бота на свой сервер',
          color=0xff9900
          )
          await ctx.reply(embed=embbod)
      elif comname == 'clear':
            embcle = discord.Embed(
            title='`Информация о команде >clear`',
            description='**Описание:**\nКоманда для очистки сообщений в чате\n**Использование:**\n>clear (кол-во сообщений)',
            color=0xff9900
            )
            embcle.set_footer(text='() - обязательный аргумент')
            await ctx.reply(embed=embcle)
            
      elif comname == 'mute':
           embmut = discord.Embed(
           title='`Информация о команде >mute`',
           description='**Описание:**\nКоманда чтобы заглушить участника\n**Использование:**\n>mute (@участник) <причина>',
           color=0xff9900
           )
           embmut.set_footer(text='() - обязательно, <> - необязательно')
           await ctx.reply(embed=embmut)

      elif comname == 'unmute':
           embenm = discord.Embed(
           title='`Информация о команде >unmute`',
           description='**Описание:**\nКомнда чтобы снять ограничение чата с участника\n**Использование:**\n>unmute (@участник)',
           color=0xff9900
           )
           embenm.set_footer(text='() - обязательно')
           await ctx.reply(embed=embenm)
           
      elif comname == 'kick':
           embkik = discord.Embed(
           title='`Информация о команде >kick`',
           description='**Описание:**\nИзгнание пользователя с сервера\n**Использование:**\n>kick (@участник) <причина>'
           )
           emkik.set_footer(text='() - обязательно, <> - необязательно')
           await ctx.reply(embed=embkik)
           
      elif comname == 'ban':
          embban = discord.Embed(
          title='`Информация о команде >ban`',
          description='**Описание:**\nКоманда для блокировки пользователя\n**Использование:**\n>ban (@участник) <причина>',
          color=0xff9900
          )
          embban.set_footer(text='() - обязательно, <> - необязательно')
          await ctx.reply(embed=embban)
          
      elif comname == 'nick':
          embnik = discord.Embed(
          title='`Информация о команде >nick`',
          description='**Описание:**\nКоманда для изменения ника пользователю\n**Использование:**\n>nick (@участник) <новый ник>',
          color=0xff9900
          )
          embnik.set_footer(text='() - обязательно, <> - обязательно')
          await ctx.reply(embed=embnik)
          
      elif comname == 'avatar':
          embava = discord.Embed(
          title='`Информация о команде >avatar`',
          description='**Описание:**\nКоманда для просмотра аватара пользователя\n**Использование:**\n>avatar (@участник)',
          color=0xff9900
          )
          embava.set_footer(text='() - необязательно')
          await ctx.reply(embed=embava)

      elif comname == 'say':
          embsay = discord.Embed(
          title='`Информация о команде >say`',
          description='**Описание:**\nКоманда для письма сообщений от имени бота\n**Использование:**\n>say (сообщение)',
          color=0xff9900
          )
          embsay.set_footer(text='() - обязательно')
          await ctx.reply(embed=embsay)

      elif comname == 'embsay':
          embemb = discord.Embed(
          title='`Информация о команде >embsay`',
          description='**Описание:**\nКоманда для для письма от имени бота, вебхуком\n**Использование:**\n>embsay (сообщение)',
          color=0xff9900
          )
          embemb.set_footer(text='() - обязательно')
          await ctx.reply(embed=embemb)

      elif comname == 'automode':
          embnun = discord.Embed(
          title='`Информация о команде >automode`',
          description='**Описание:**\nКоманда для включение и выключения автомодерации на мат\n**Использование:**\n>automode',
          color=0xff9900
          )
          await ctx.reply(embed=embnun)
          
      elif comname == 'fox':
          embfox = discord.Embed(
          title='`Информация о команде >fox`',
          description='**Описание:**\nРандомные фото лисичек',
          color=0xff9900
          )
          await ctx.reply (embed=embfox)

      elif comname == 'dog':
          embdog = discord.Embed(
          title='`Информация о команде >dog`',
          description='**Описание:**\nРандомные фото собачек',
          color=0xff9900
          )
          await ctx.reply (embed=embdog)

      elif comname == 'cat':
          embcat = discord.Embed(
          title='`Информация о команде >cat`',
          description='**Описание:**\nРандомные фото котиков',
          color=0xff9900
          )
          await ctx.reply (embed=embcat)
          components = [
          Select(
          placeholder = 'SelectMenu',
          options = [ 
          SelectOption(label="SelectMenu1", value="value1",),
          SelectOption(label="SelectMenu2", value="value2"),
          SelectOption(label="SelectMenu3", value="value3"),
          SelectOption(label = "SelectMenu4", value = "value4"),
          SelectOption(label="SelectMenu5", value="value5"),
          SelectOption(label="SelectMenu6", value="value6"),
          SelectOption(label = "SelectMenu7", value = "value7"),
          SelectOption(label = "SelectMenu8", value = "value8")
          ])]

@bot.event
async def on_select_option(interaction):
    await interaction.respond(type=6)
    if interaction.values[0] == "value1":
        await interaction.author.send("Menu 1")
    elif interaction.values[0] == "value2":
        await interaction.author.send("Menu 2")
```

**Если кому надо полный код бота, а он большой 600+ строк, то если он нужен то могу скинь файлом в дискорде, мой дискорд *halflite#5696***
Вдруг чего, это никакой не пиар!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
await ctx.reply(embed=embcat,
    components=[
        Select(
            placeholder='SelectMenu',
            options=[ 
                SelectOption(label="SelectMenu1", value="value1",),
                SelectOption(label="SelectMenu2", value="value2"),
                SelectOption(label="SelectMenu3", value="value3"),
                SelectOption(label="SelectMenu4", value="value4"),
                SelectOption(label="SelectMenu5", value="value5"),
                SelectOption(label="SelectMenu6", value="value6"),
                SelectOption(label="SelectMenu7", value="value7"),
                SelectOption(label="SelectMenu8", value="value8")
            ]
        )
    ]
)
```